# R - Extract (p)heatmap colors to use in polygon fill

Tags: r, polygon, heatmap, fill, pheatmap

I created a heatmap in R which is n*k in size, is it possible to extract the individual colors used for an ith element?

For example n=3 (columns) and k=50 (rows), n is an arbitrary level of severity and k represents a district in the UK.

I have the polygons for these districts and I want to create 3 separate maps based on the severity using the same colors from the overall heatmap as the fill for the polygons for consistency.

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: You can specify custom colors to a heatmap, which in turn, you can use to color anything else.

Comment: I think he's interested in mapping the exact shades of colours across to the map of polygons. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand how this works, I had to look into the code of `pheatmap`.
Let's first generate a matrix:

```
A <- matrix(1:10, 2, 5)
```

The default palette is defined as

```
pal <- colorRampPalette(rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 7, name = "RdYlBu")))(100)
```

The idea is then to define break values and assign a color to each of the intervals defined by the breaks:

```
bks <- pheatmap:::generate_breaks(A, length(pal), center = F)
A2 <- pheatmap:::scale_colours(A, col=pal, breaks=bks)
```

Matrix `A2` contains the colors associated to each cell of `A`:

```
A2
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]     
# [1,] "#4575B4" "#ABD0E4" "#F4FBD2" "#FEDF8F" "#EF6D48"
# [2,] "#77A6CE" "#E0F3F7" "#FEF4AF" "#FCA86B" "#D73027"
```

Finally, we can represent `A` with colors defined in `A2` first with `pheatmap`, and also with `image`:

```
pheatmap(t(A[,5:1]),cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols = F)
```

[image: With pheatmap]

```
image(A, col=A2)
```

[image: With image]

Ref: [Kolde, R. (2013). pheatmap: Pretty Heatmaps.](http://cran.r-project.org/package=pheatmap)

Comment: If you changed `A <- matrix(rnorm(10), 2, 5)` This doesn't seem to work. Can you explain why? Is it due to the size of the values?

Comment: Can you try `image(matrix(1:10,2,5), col=A2)`? I think `image` is confused if `A` contains random values.

Comment: I also tried to fill `A` with random values, and I got in `A2` the correct colors attributed by `pheatmap`. I checked on [this site](http://hex-color.com/).

Comment: Thanks @Vincent, worked perfectly. Once I had the A2 dataset it was easy for me to cycle through the districts using the ith element of the contents of A2 as the fill of my polygon. Cheers. :)